# How to install "tidyquant" package to R 3.4.0?

Tags: r, tidyquant

Good afternoon. I face a problem, connected with "tidyquant" package installation.
When I type:

```
install.packages ("tidyquant")
```

The installation process begins, but some time later I get several warning messages:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘PerformanceAnalytics’ is not available
also installing the dependencies ‘listenv’, ‘future’, ‘globals’, ‘ellipsis’, ‘furrr’, ‘hms’, ‘warp’, ‘glue’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘rlang’, ‘tibble’, ‘tidyselect’, ‘vctrs’, ‘cpp11’, ‘recipes’, ‘rsample’, ‘padr’, ‘readr’, ‘stringi’, ‘slider’, ‘anytime’, ‘dplyr’, ‘Quandl’, ‘riingo’, ‘alphavantager’, ‘tidyr’, ‘timetk’

Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

When the installation process is finished, I type:

```
library(tidyquant)
```

and receive the following error:

```
Error in library(tidyquant) : there is no ‘tidyquant’ package
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What happens if you run `install.packages(PerformanceAnalytics)`?

Comment: I run:
`install.packages("PerformanceAnalytics")`

and get the following message:
`Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘PerformanceAnalytics’ is not available (for R version 3.4.0)
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'`

By the way, how is "PerformanceAnalytics" package related to "tidyquant" package?

Comment: You need to install a newer version of R. Your version is several years old.

Comment: Will the upgrade of R lead to deletetion or influence R data, stored on my computer, anyhow? And should I delete the old version of RStudio before installing the new one?

Comment: No, it has no effect on your files. You will have to re-install packages as you need them, however.

Comment: RStudio has no bearing on any of this, but sure it doesn't hurt to update it if you're using an older version of that as well. The latest version it's on is v1.3.